# How InetAddress.getLocalHost() works?

Tags: java, networking, java-7

I'm trying to get how `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` works. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost()) says that it retrieves the name of the host from the system and then resolves it into an `InetAddress`. What exactly does "resolve into InetAddess" mean? Does it simply ask DNS to resolve a hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `InetAddress.java` source:

```
 private static InetAddress[] getAddressesFromNameService(String host, InetAddress reqAddr)
        throws UnknownHostException
    {
        InetAddress[] addresses = null;
        boolean success = false;
        UnknownHostException ex = null;

        // Check whether the host is in the lookupTable.
        // 1) If the host isn't in the lookupTable when
        //    checkLookupTable() is called, checkLookupTable()
        //    would add the host in the lookupTable and
        //    return null. So we will do the lookup.
        // 2) If the host is in the lookupTable when
        //    checkLookupTable() is called, the current thread
        //    would be blocked until the host is removed
        //    from the lookupTable. Then this thread
        //    should try to look up the addressCache.
        //     i) if it found the addresses in the
        //        addressCache, checkLookupTable()  would
        //        return the addresses.
        //     ii) if it didn't find the addresses in the
        //         addressCache for any reason,
        //         it should add the host in the
        //         lookupTable and return null so the
        //         following code would do a lookup itself.

  ...

if (host.equalsIgnoreCase("localhost")) {
  InetAddress[] local = new InetAddress[] { impl.loopbackAddress() }; // {0x7f,0x00,0x00,0x01}
  addresses = local;
  success = true;
  break;
}
```

To recap:

- both `InetAddress.getAllByName()` and `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` resolve the address by calling `getAddressesFromNameService()`
- The JVM maintains its own cache of hostname -> IP address mapping.
- If the address is not in the cache (`lookupTable` or `addressCache`) it will call the operating system's DNS (exact behavior may vary per JVM implementation).
- For localhost sepcificly - there is a specific case inside `getAddressesFromNameService()`

Comment: I guess, the JVM cache is the root cause of why I'm asking the question. Thanks!